# disableurlrewriting not working with tomcat 6 when going from http to https

Tags: tomcat, https, tomcat6, jsessionid

I am trying to remove jsessionId from the URL. I have taken the route of achieving this via the 'disableURLRewriting' attribute.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context disableURLRewriting="true">
</Context>
```

This is working fine when I directly access the site using https.

However I have configured the webapp to always redirect to https via a security constraint in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

The problem is that when I access the website using http and it gets re-directed to https, in that case disableURLRewriting doesn't seem to work and the jsessionId shows up in the URL.

Tomcat version is 6.0.43.

So my question is will the jsessionId always show us when http is redirected to https regardless of disableURLRewriting ?

I know that there is the option of using filters such as Tuckey. Would that be resilient to the http to https transition ?